# Image fixed in page without moving when reducing

Tags: html, css, positioning

I created this class with CSS:

```
.leaf {
background: url();
position: fixed;
background-size: 300px;
z-index: 0;
height: 206px;
width: 300px;
top: -5%;
left: -7%;
}
```

Which shows a leaf in the background. What I want to do is to not make this image move when the page is zoomed, or even when the display's width is less then 1024px. It has to stick in that position!

Thank you very much

Comment: What do you mean by _zoomed_? When the user has, for example, pressed **CTRL** + **+** to zoom? I don't think this is possible.

Comment: I'm sorry, I explained that wrong. I don't know how is it called in english. When you 'reduce' the page so the width dicreases

Comment: Your CSS should then work as expected. Though you might want to substitute `position: fixed` with `position: absolute` and see if that changes anything. Depends on where `.leaf` is positioned in your document. Else try to provide the HTML you're using.